# Any workaround for ng-repeat inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-view

I have a Single page application that uses ngRoute to chane pages on an ng-view. The switching works well. I came into a problem where one of the html pages shown by ngview has an ngRepeat table. After reading several posts ive noticed ngrepeat cannot be used inside ngview. Any workaround?

index.html(master page)

```
...
<div id="main" class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
...
```

EventList.html (displayed by ng-view)

```
<div id="listView" >
    <div ng-controller="EventListCtrl">
        <table class="one">
            <thead>
            <th>EventId</th>
            <th>Heading</th>
            <th>EventDate</th>
            <th>EventTime</th>
            <th>UserId</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items ">
                    <td>{{item.EventId}}</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

ng-repeat="item in items " not populating, my angular functions all work fine

Comment: this doesn't even make any sense.  What do you mean, `ngRepeat` can't be used inside an `ngView`?  There is no such restriction.  Please show a working example of your expected and actual results to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Angular by default can only have 1 ng-view active at any time. You can get around this by putting your ng-view inside a div, then control the visibility of that div by using the ng-if directive.

```
<div ng-if="someCondition">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>

<div ng-if="!someCondition">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Note: having mulitple ng-views is really not recommended.

EDIT: Upon re-reading your question, I think maybe you meant using ng-repeat inside an ng-view element?

```
<ng-view>
   <div ng-repeat="...."> </div>
</ng-view>
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: I have an <div ngView> that displays an html page, the html page displayed has a <table > .....<tr ng-repeat="item in items"> ... but never populates. I will try to edit my post to add the code

Comment: For as far as I can tell, your code should work just fine. Are you sure "items" gets populated by your controller?